# AngularJS lazy loading components with ngNewRoute

Tags: angularjs, lazy-loading, angularjs-new-router, angular-new-router

I want to make an application that uses [AngularJS new router](https://angular.github.io/router). I decided to wrap every component to a new module and lazily load the component (module, controller and template) with ocLazyLoad when user changed the route to that component. I think I have to load module with ocLazyLoad but don't know where to write this code!